# Using Shiny to dispay conditional ggvis OR ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggvis

Hi im using shiny to display some plots. I need to use both ggplot and ggvis as both have some funtionality the other doesnt have. My problem is I want to display a ggplot when my slider value is less than 100 and the ggvis when it is equal to 100. I can show both plots at once but cant find a way to be conditional on which plot needs to be displayed. Code below any help appreciated.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  vis <- reactive({
  input$goButton
    isolate({
      output$myPlot <- renderPlot ({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=wt)) + geom_point()
      })
      mtcars %>% ggvis(~mpg, ~wt)
     })
  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
  })

SHINY UI
________
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel( "Test Plots"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
    ,checkboxInput("ckFilter", h4("Filters"), value = TRUE),
     conditionalPanel( "input.ckFilter"
    #,h4("Filter")#,
    ,sliderInput("zoom","Zoom Level", 1,10, value=1)
    ),                  
    checkboxInput("ckAxes", h4("Axes"), value = FALSE),
    conditionalPanel("input.ckAxes"
    , selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", xaxis_vars, selected = "All_likelihood")
    , selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", yaxis_vars, selected = "All_consequence"))
    ,
checkboxInput("ckHighlight", h4("Highlight"), value = FALSE),
conditionalPanel("input.ckQuadrants",
numericInput("xbound", "X boundary",min=0,max=1,step=0.01, value = 0.5),
numericInput("ybound", "Y boundary", value = 75000),
numericInput("yminV", "Minimum y limit", value = 10), 
numericInput("ymaxV", "Maximum y limit", value = 450000),
selectInput("ytrans", "y Transformation", c("linear", "log", "sqrt"),selected = "sqrt" ))
# ,checkboxInput("logscale", "Log scale", value = FALSE)
),

column(8,plotOutput("myPlot"),
wellPanel(
span("Number of entities selected:",textOutput("n_entities", inline = T), ", highlighted:",textOutput("n_highlighted", inline = T) 
)
)

),
 column(8,ggvisOutput("plot1"))
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `conditionalPanel` for this. For example, to display the `plotOutput` only when the zoom slider is less than 10 you can do, in your `ui.R`:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zoom < '10'",plotOutput("myPlot"))
```

And for the ggvisOutput:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zoom == '10'",ggvisOutput("plot1"))
```

Comment: I am facing some challenge in generating ggplot bar and line charts basis input user selection. I hope you would help me and be able to suggest. Thanking you!! I have posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078480/r-shiny-ggplot-bar-and-line-charts-with-dynamic-variable-selection-and-y-axis-to